# installing Sybase module for python

Tags: python, sap-ase

I'm having some trouble installing the Sybase python module. I've downloaded the zip file, unzipped and run python setup.py install in that directory. However, I get this error;

Directory I:\Sybase\sql15\OCS-12_5;OCS-15_0\include does not exist - cannot build

Can anyone tell me what this means? I assume the above directory is my Sybase directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've Sybase 15.0 installed on my machine and I've the following directory:

```
C:\Sybase\OCS-15_0\include
```

---

Do you have Sybase installed? If not, that's your problem.